# Extract data from plot in r

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, nonlinear-functions

I have made a plot using ggplot on R and using the function `nls` because it was a non linear regression, now I would like to extract data from the graph, specifically I would like to know the value of the 2 curves in the graph when the y value is 0, and I have to do it using R..

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302851/extract-coefficients-from-ggplot2-created-nls-fit It might do the trick for you

Comment: Thank you very much I had not seen it

Comment: Technically this isn't extracting data from the **graph** -- it's getting the source data from the generating object.  If you want to get a few data points from a graph, use `locator` or `identify` ; otherwise dump the graph into EngaugeDigitizer or DataThief