# Is there a way to see geom_smooth statistical details?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

So, is there  a way to see the geom_smooth parameters like R, R², Fit Expression?

Comment: Take a look at `ggplot_build()`

Comment: It doesn't show me the R, R-squared or the fit formula..

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/add-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph

Comment: Alternatively [ggstatsplot](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/) has some more advanced visualizations, with added information although I'm uncertain how flexible the package is when it comes to smoother choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2: how to get values for the regression line equation, r^2 and p value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365724/ggplot2-how-to-get-values-for-the-regression-line-equation-r2-and-p-value)

Comment: OP, [check here for the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365724/ggplot2-how-to-get-values-for-the-regression-line-equation-r2-and-p-value).  `geom_smooth()` uses `method` as an argument to create that line.  If you specify `method="lm"`, then the parameters should be the same as those you would get using the `lm()` function to create a model.  You can then use `summary()` of that model to see the relevant parameters.  If you can share dataset and code, you might get a more descriptive answer.