# fitdistr in rpy2

Tags: python, r, statistics, rpy2, rpython

I've a 1D list of data, that I want to fit into a distribution using either least squares or maximum likelihood, as presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290081/fitting-data-to-distributions), but I want to do it from python instead of the R interactive shell.

I got [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) installed, and would like to use the `fitdistr` function from within the interactive `ipython` shell, as I have imported the data in a list.

Where is this function, and how do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is in the R package MASS

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

MASS = importr('MASS')

# the function is now at MASS.fitdistr
```