# Python analog of mvrnorm's empirical setting when generating a multivariate distribution?

Tags: python, r, numpy

So in `R`'s `MASS` package there is a function called `mvrnorm` for generating multivariate distributions. It has an argument called `empirical` which, when set to to TRUE, mu (means) and sigma (covariance matrix) specifiy the emperical, not the population mean and covariance matrix.

In short, when you pull out samples the means and variances are very similar to what was prescribed.

Is there anything similar in python?
I have been unable to find anything like this in numpy, for example.

Comment: Why not just use R? R is specifically tailored for statistical computing, considered on par with the statistical packages -Stata, SPSS, and SAS. Python is a general-purpose language which though equipped can do statistical analyses its libraries are not as extensive as R in this area. Hence, econometricians and biostatisticans are strong contributors to the R community, not quite Python. Finally, do note these two can be used together.

Comment: @Parfait I use R daily and have for a long time. Sadly, one cannot build experiments in R. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @lnNoam What do you mean by "build experiments"?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson. I'm making a psychophysical experiment which requires sampling from a multivariate distribution.

Comment: @lnNoam Doesn't sound like something outside of R's capability. That said, I fully appreciate the fact that just because R *can* do something doesn't mean you must/should use it.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
MASS = importr('MASS')                       # Must use R: install.packages('MASS')
r = robjects.r

np.matrix(MASS.mvrnorm(n = 10, mu = r.c(0,0), Sigma = r.diag(2), empirical = True))
```

[This helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163472/fitdistr-in-rpy2)

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
mvrnorm is equivalent to np.random.multivariate_normal

This geometrical property can be seen in two dimensions by plotting generated data-points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mean = [0, 0]
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 100]]  # diagonal covariance

x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000).T

plt.plot(x, y, 'x')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmwmO.png)

Have a look at:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html

Comment: It's not the same. The `empirical` argument in R generates sample which has the same covariance as provided for the distribution. In the case of numpy, the generated samples covariance can vary a bit.

Comment: How do we have same distribution for both r and python?